# REACT REDUX: Help resolve Issues accessing global variables

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js

I am working on setting up a global state in react redux for my project. After setting up redux, store, and slice for the User; and upon dispatching an action to populate the global state for the User, I am unable to retrieve the updated values for the states. Below are copies of my codes:

```
// UserSlice.js

import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
  isLoading: false,
  user: {
    userName: '',
    email: '',
    image: '',
    role: '',
  },
};

export const userStatusSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'userStatus',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    userInfo: (state, action) => {
      state.user.userName = action.payload.name; // comes from session
      state.user.email = action.payload.email; // comes from session
      state.user.role = action.payload.role; // only this value comes from payload
      state.user.image = action.payload.image; // comes from session
      state.user.isLoading = action.payload.isLoading;
    },
  },
});

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { userInfo } = userStatusSlice.actions;

export default userStatusSlice.reducer;
```

```
// store.js

import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import userStatusSlice from './slices/userSlice/userStatus';

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    userStatus: userStatusSlice,
  },
});
```

```
// page.js

import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { userInfo } from '../slices/userSlice/userStatus';

export default function FirstPageModal() {
  const { data: session } = useSession(); //logs Authenticated user information {name, email, image} from user

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { isLoading, user } = useSelector((store) => store.userStatus); //Fetches values from the REDUX userStatus global store

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    //Assigning User Info:
    let buttonValue = e.target.value;
    const { name, email: sessionEmail, image: sessionImage } = session.user; // data from authenticated user session
    const { userName, email, role, image } = user; // data from redux store

    //Re-Assigning User info:
    userName = name;
    email = sessionEmail;
    role = buttonValue;
    image = sessionImage;

    if (role === 'Brand') {
      dispatch(userInfo({ userName, email, role, image }));
      console.log(user); // logs empty values from redux store - expected to log values from above with updated role
    } else if (role === 'Agency') {
      dispatch(userInfo({ userName, email, role, image }));
      console.log(user); //logs empty values from redux store - expected to log values from above with updated role
    } else {
      console.log('This role does not exit');
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <button
          type="button"
          className=""
          onClick={handleClick}
          value="Brand"
        >
          As a Brand
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          className=""
          onClick={handleClick}
          value="Agency"
        >
          As an Agency
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Upon logging "user" in the condition to the console, I was expecting to get back the session information as well as the updated role. What I got back instead was an empty object from the initial global state. Can you help point out what I am missing here?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you invoke `userInfo` in `page.js`, you need to create the object you pass to userInfo `{ userName, email, role, image }` so that key names match the key names in the reducer definition. The fix would be

```
 dispatch(userInfo({ name: userName, email, role, image, isLoading: true }));
```

EDIT: the `export const { userInfo } = userStatusSlice.actions;` syntax was correct in the end

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried that, and got an error: 
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: (0 , _slices_userSlice_userStatus__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_10__.userInfo) is not a function

.....That I thiink is because 'userInfo' is an Object in "UserSlice.js"

Comment: Can you correct your original question? You reassign new values to constants which is confusing